# Resolve netbios-name and pass it to mount.cifs in script

Tags: shell-script, scripting, samba

I have a script that mounts all the shares from my Windows computer. It's basically:

```
mount.cifs //192.168.0.7/pictures ~/otherpc/pictures -o user=me,domain=mynetwork,password=12345,vers=3.0
```

..for about 10 lines.

Problem is, my network is DHCP. So every now and then I have to go change the IP in this script.

The script used to work this way:

```
mount.cifs //OTHERPC/pictures ~/otherpc/pictures -o user=me,domain=mynetwork,password=12345,ver=3.0
```

But at some point it started producing the error:

```
mount error: could not resolve address for OTHERPC: Unknown error
```

Nautilus resolves the name without a problem, though.

Is there a way to resolve the IP, store it in a variable and then use mount.cifs with //$variable instead of the IP directly in the script?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem after an `do-release-upgrade` to Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. All shares that mounted happily before ended with this ugly

```
mount error: could not resolve address for server.domain.local: Unknown error
```

`nslookup` was resolving correctly, `syslog` and `strace` did not show anything.

In the end, the problem was the `.local` domain together with a change (possibly during the release upgrade) in the `/etc/nsswitch.conf` witch put the mDNS Avahi/Bonjour daemon `mdns4_minimal` before dns lookup.

So the problem was solved after I changed the order from

```
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] dns
```

to

```
hosts:          files dns mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] resolve [!UNAVAIL=return]
```

I can't remember all helpfull links, but this one certainly did the trick: https://askubuntu.com/a/853284/810573

Answer (score 0):

I see two options you should try before fiddling around with storing the IP in a variable. (Besides, unless the servers already have a hostname, how will you figure out the new IP?)

- Try mounting with hostname instead of IP, if it is a dynamic IP.

  ```
  mount.cifs //cifs.server.com/pictures ~/otherpc/pictures -o user=me,domain=mynetwork,password=12345,vers=3.0
  ```
- If the network is under your control, make DHCP reservations for the IP of the cifs servers.

Comment: This might have been useful information in my post, the script used to be like you described in your first option. mount.cifs //otherpc/pictures and so on and it worked fine. But at some point, the script started giving the error "mount error: could not resolve address for OTHERPC: Unknown error." That's why I changed it to the IP. Nautilus can resolve the netbios name without a problem, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the IP with `nmblookup NAME | head -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 1`

Put it into variable `NAME_IP` with `NAME_IP="$(nmblookup NAME | head -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 1)"`